# How to count total id that answering a quiz in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like this:

**Quiz**

```
quizNum | quizName
------------------
1       | chapter 1
2       | chapter 2
3       | chapter 3
```

**studentassessment**

```
stuNum | quizNum | assessmentMark
-----------------------------------
2012   | 1       | 10
2012   | 2       | 8
2013   | 1       | 10
2014   | 1       | 5
```

I want to get result something like this

```
quizNum | quizName      | attempedstudent 
--------------------------------------------
1       | chapter 1     | 3        
2       | chapter 2     | 1        
3       | chapter 3     | 0
```

description : all two table are connected.. i want to count total student that have done their quiz by quziNum

this is example combination that i tried :

```
$sql = "select a.quizNum, (count(a.stuNum)) as attemptedstudent ,c.quizName,c.quizDateFrom from studentassessment a join quiz c on a.quizNum=c.quizNum";
```

i wrote like that and the result show it count all the stuNum (student). is it i have to used another way such as distinct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `left join` of `Quiz` to `studentassessment` to make sure that all data from `Quiz` is shown along with the count.

```
select
q.quizNum,
q.quizName,
count(sa.stuNum) as attempedstudent
from Quiz q
left join studentassessment sa on sa.quizNum = q.quizNum
group by q.quizNum;
```